# Unable to add printer: Unauthorized when adding a printer using the CUPS web interface

Tags: docker, cups, printer

I have setup a CUPS server with the web interface. Sadly I'm unable to add a printer by doing the following steps:

- Browser (REMOTE_SERVER_IP:631)
- Administration tab
- Local Printers
- HP Printer (HPLIP)
- Connection
- Add Printer (name and all the good stuff)
- Select model
- Select Driver
- Error

[image]

At this point I get the message: `Unable to add printer: Unauthorized`. My configuration file looks like this:

```
# Disable cups internal logging - use logrotate instead
MaxLogSize 0

# Log general information in error_log - change "warn" to "debug"
# for troubleshooting...
LogLevel warn
#PageLogFormat

Listen /run/cups/cups.sock
Listen 0.0.0.0:631
Port 631

BrowseAddress *.*.*.*:631
BrowseAllow all

# Show shared printers on the local network.
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols all

# Default authentication type, when authentication is required...
DefaultAuthType None

# Web interface setting...
WebInterface Yes

# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow All
</Location>

# Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow All
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow All
</Location>

# Restrict access to log files...
<Location /admin/log>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow All
</Location>
```

I'm using the following [Dockerfile](https://github.com/davidgatti/wireless-printing-with-docker-on-a-raspberry-pi/blob/master/cups/Dockerfile) to build and start the whole thing. I also provide a new user inside the image.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already fixed this but I had the same problem. Solved it by changing "Order deny,allow" to "Order allow,deny" and remove all Authentication stuff.

This is my configuration file:

```
#
# Configuration file for the CUPS scheduler.  See "man cupsd.conf" for a
# complete description of this file.
#

# Log general information in error_log - change "warn" to "debug"
# for troubleshooting...
LogLevel warn
PageLogFormat

# Deactivate CUPS' internal logrotating, as we provide a better one, especially
# LogLevel debug2 gets usable now
MaxLogSize 0

# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
Listen 631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock

# Show shared printers on the local network.
Browsing Off
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd

# Default authentication type, when authentication is required...
DefaultAuthType None

# Web interface setting...
WebInterface Yes

# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>

# Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType None
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

# Restrict access to log files...
<Location /admin/log>
  AuthType None
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

# Set the default printer/job policies...
<Policy default>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    #Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    #Order deny,allow
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
    AuthType None
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>
</Policy>

# Set the authenticated printer/job policies...
<Policy authenticated>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>

  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order allow,deny
  </Limit>
</Policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a user to be admin of cups instead of allowing all.
The simplest way is to add the user to `lpadmin` group.

Check this:
[How can I enable remote access to the Admin page in CUPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/836266/how-can-i-enable-remote-access-to-the-admin-page-in-cups)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the "unauthorized" error when trying to add a printer.
More search revealed there's a problem accessing CUPS 2.2.7 with Google Chrome.  It won't ask for your user name and password, it goes straight to "unauthorized".  (On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS,  CUPS 2.2.7 is the default.)

Using a different browser, specifically Firefox, is an easy work-around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permissions for the operations as well

```
<Policy default>
  <Limit All>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow all
  </Limit>
</Policy>
```

For my configuration I went with `Allow @LOCAL` instead of `Allow all` so that I would accept all local connections, but your requirements may differ.

It also appears that the `Location` settings are recursive, so it is sufficient to have

```
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
```

And all the other paths (/admin, etc.) will be included.